# Join tables on fields that don't match?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to join 2 tables but the contents of the fields I'm trying to join on are in different formats.

```
Table1 name field is just is normal - Dave, Bob, Gary
Table2 name field some of them have brackets after - Dave (GB), Bob, Gary (JAP)
```

In vb.net I would just split the name by " (", is there a similar thing I can do in Access in the JOIN query?

I.E

```
INNER JOIN People ON (SPLIT(Moves.name, " (", "") = People.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join on the result of `InStr`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on InStr(t2.name, t1.name & ' (')=1
```

`t1` has "clean" strings; `t2` has strings with `(...)` suffixes. The above join expression appends space+open parenthesis string `' ('` to the field from `t1`, and checks that the field from `t2` starts with that string.

Comment: Cheers, this works, only returns the records with (..) though, so I did with OR t2.name = t1.name. This query seems to be pretty poor for performance though, takes over 10 seconds to search 50000 records.

Comment: @user2096512 You are right about the performance - indexes are useless for imprecise joins like this. If you have an option to alter the schema, consider defining a view that chops off the end portion of the name. This could speed things up a little.

Answer (score 0):

String `REPLACE` and `SUBSTRING` approach could be viable

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN 'Dave' = REPLACE('Dave (GB)',SUBSTRING('Dave (GB)', CHARINDEX(' ', 'Dave (GB)'), Len('Dave (GB)')), '')  THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'NO' END
```

Replace 'Dave' and 'Dave (GB)' with the column names in your respective tables use the below condition in your join.

```
    'Dave' = REPLACE('Dave (GB)',SUBSTRING('Dave (GB)', CHARINDEX(' ', 'Dave (GB)'), Len('Dave (GB)')), '')
```

Comment: It may be better to use CHARINDEX or PATINDEX to find the '(' character and extract and TRIM the characters preceding it, then use the result in the JOIN expression.  For large data sets, this could cause performance issues, but would avoid hard coding based upon a specific value.

Comment: Found this answer a little confusing so went with the one above, thanks anyway.